# Running GNU screen through SSH, the shell is not a login shell?

Tags: shell, ssh, login, gnu-screen

I'm using screen (the problematically named terminal session manager) on a remote system accessed over SSH - to run long running processes and such. I have eventually started using a command to attach directly to the screen session, instead of first logging in through SSH and then start screen:

```
ssh -t hostname screen -xRR
```

The use of the `-xRR` is to attach to the existing screen session, if available, otherwise just create a new one. The problem is that when a new session is created, it is not created as a login shell:

```
$ shopt -q login_shell; echo $?
1
```

and as a result, login session setup (running `.profile` and friends) isn't done and then parts of the setup is missing, compared to first using SSH to login and then running `screen` - in which case the shell SSH starts is a login shell and it is setup properly and screen I guess inherits the environment.

I tried using the `-l` flag on screen, which is documented as "Login mode", but it doesn't help - I think it only updates the "login time" for things like `who`.

Any idea how to get screen to run a login shell?

Comment: I normally refer to it as "GNU Screen" or similar to try to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the man pages of GNU `screen`:

> **-s** program
>
> sets the default shell to the program specified, instead of the value
> in the environment variable `$SHELL` (or "`/bin/sh`" if not defined). This
> can also be defined through the "`shell`" .screenrc command.

...

> **shell** command
>
> Set the command to be used to create a new shell. This overrides the
> value of the environment variable `$SHELL`. This is useful if you’d like
> to run a tty-enhancer which is expecting to execute the program
> specified in `$SHELL`. **If the command begins with a ‘-’ character, the
> shell will be started as a login-shell. Typical shells do only minimal
> initialization when not started as a login-shell. E.g. Bash will not
> read your `~/.bashrc` unless it is a login-shell.**
>
> `defshell` is currently a synonym to the `shell` .screenrc command.

So you have two options:

1. Run the following command to ensure that `bash` is launched as a login shell:

   ```
   ssh -t hostname screen -xRR -s -bash
   ```
2. If you want this behavior to be the default one, add the following line to your `$HOME/.screenrc` file on the destination host (or wherever you run your `screen` command):

   ```
   shell -bash
   ```

Comment: I've noticed the `shell` command, but didn't find how to invoke it from the command line, so - thank you. It looks to be working well - in that the shell is now a login shell, but now for some reason, in the login shell, ANSI character graphics (like used in `mc` or `htop`) show as "�" (the unicode decode failure glyph). I can fix this by adding `-U`, but this only happens with `-s -bash`, while when setting `-s bash` it's not a problem - what gives?

Comment: Apparently the problem is that with a non-login shell, screen uses the locale environment variables passed from the local shell though SSH. My local locale is `en_IL.UTF-8` while the default login shell locale inside screen is `C.UTF-8`. How would that cause this unicode decoding issue is beyond me, but I can workaround the problem by setting `LC_NAME=en_IL` in the `~/.profile` file.